# Time isn't showing correctly in React. How can I get rid of the PM or format it so that it doesn't show there?

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3U6y.png)
Screenshot from CodeSandbox

Comment: Remember to follow the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask), and definitely remember to use [proper markdown](/markdown) in your post.

Comment: `new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB');`

Answer (score 0):

`new Date().toISOString()` returns string in this format "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MSZ". Manipulate to get your desired output:

```
let simpleDate = (new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

Comment: I'm not being able to make this work Tushar. Can you give me further guidance?

Comment: I'm not being able to make this work Tushar. Can you give me further guidance?

Comment: console.log at different steps and let us know what you ar getting. Like console.log(new Date()).toISOString())